# Core data crash fetching

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is the what the crash report says :-

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[_PFFetchPlanHeader _genericValueForKey:withIndex:flags:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b24730

The part of the code where the crash is happening :-

```
    let managedContext = CoreDataHelper.getNSMangedObjectContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: NotificationPersistenceHelper.UserNotification_entity)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(NotificationPersistenceHelper.uniqueID) = %@", argumentArray: [uniqueId!])
    do{
         let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        return  !results.isEmpty
    }catch let error as NSError{
        AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.error("Fetch Failed : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return false
```

the crash is happening at the following line from the above code:-

```
  let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Any help on why the crash is happening guys tried a lot but was not able to find the reason for the crash. Any help guys?.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to replace     `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(NotificationPersistenceHelper.uniqueID) = %@", argumentArray: [uniqueId!])`
 with     `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueID == %@", argumentArray: [uniqueId!])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of this**

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(NotificationPersistenceHelper.uniqueID) = %@", argumentArray: [uniqueId!])
```

**Try this one**

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(NotificationPersistenceHelper.uniqueID), uniqueId!)
```