# Fetching data from core data crashing for iOS version 12

Tags: swift, core-data

Here is what crash report says:-

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[_PFFetchPlanHeader
>   _genericValueForKey:withIndex:flags:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b24730

**Crash report** for the below crash is:-

> Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
>                       0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1edc58d70 objc_msgSend + 16
>                       1  CoreData                       0x1f16b653c _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty + 252
>                       2  Foundation                     0x1ef41c3cc -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 808
>                       3  Foundation                     0x1ef41bfc8 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 228
>                       4  CoreData                       0x1f1590e8c -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 3476
>                       5  Quickride                      0x1044f6d28 specialized static
>   NotificationPersistenceHelper.isNotificationAlreadyPresent(uniqueId:)
>   (NotificationPersistenceHelper.swift:284)
>                       6  Quickride                      0x104465c4c specialized NotificationHandler.saveNotification(clientNotification:)
>   (NotificationHandler.swift:58)
>                       7  Quickride                      0x1047174c8 AppStartupHandler.sessionChangeOperationCompleted()
>   (NotificationStore.swift:26)
>                       8  Quickride                      0x104718058 protocol witness for
>   SessionChangeCompletionListener.sessionChangeOperationCompleted() in
>   conformance AppStartupHandler (AppStartupHandler.swift)
>                       9  Quickride                      0x10479f4b0 SessionManagerController.notifyListenerAboutSessionChangeOpCompletion()
>   (SessionManagerController.swift:284)
>                       10 Quickride                      0x10479e638 SessionManagerController.resumeUserSession(sessionChangeCompletionListener:)
>   (SessionManagerController.swift:93)
>                       11 Quickride                      0x1047170c8 closure #1 in
>   AppStartupHandler.resumeUserSessionAndNavigateToAppropriateInitialView()
>   (AppStartupHandler.swift:38)
>                       12 Quickride                      0x104371784 thunk for @callee_owned () -> ()
>   (RideManagementModuleSessonHandler.swift)
>                       13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ee4a96c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
>                       14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ee4aa484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
>                       15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ee459b5c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 684
>                       16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ee45a2d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
>                       17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ee68c17c _pthread_wqthread + 472
>                       18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ee68ecec start_wqthread + 4

Part of code where crash occurred and this code works fine until iOS version 12  :-

```
                static func isNotificationAlreadyPresent(uniqueId :Double?) -> Bool{
                        if uniqueId == nil{
                            return false
                        }

                        let managedContext = CoreDataHelper.getNSMangedObjectContext()
                        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: NotificationPersistenceHelper.UserNotification_entity)

                        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(NotificationPersistenceHelper.uniqueID) = %@", argumentArray: [uniqueId!])
                        do{
                            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

                            return  !results.isEmpty
                        }catch let error as NSError{
                        }
                        return false
                    }

            Crash occurred at below line :-

            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Above code to fetch data from core data works fine till iOS version 11 but now for user who is using iOS version 12 this crash happened.

Could you please help me in resolving this crash, am wondering why this is giving trouble for version 12 only is there any other method specific to iOS version 12 to fetch core data or is there any issue with iOS version itself? if there what is the solution for that?

am searching this for past 2 days am not getting why it is crashing only to iOS version 12 Please any one help me to resolve this crash.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not related, but seeing `if uniqueId == nil{... return } ... uniqueId!` should be `guard let uniqueId = uniqueId else { return false} ... uniqueId`

Comment: And isn't the question solved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605662/core-data-crash-fetching ? Duplicate? It's marked as solved so I guess that's the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core data crash fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605662/core-data-crash-fetching)

Comment: Core data crash fetching - this solution will not work in all version it won't work for me

Comment: any update on this issue? am not getting any solution for this crash, please anyone can help me

Comment: @JoakimDanielson any update on this issue?